# How to get only difference from diff

Tags: linux, sed, diff

I have this code , how to improve it

```
diff  -b -i -w  out.txt out2.txt  
 | grep '^>' 
 | sed 's/^>//g' 
 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

example data (out.txt)

```
abc def ghk
abc def2 ghk
abc def ghk

123 333 555
566 3423 23
566 3423 3542
```

example data (out2.txt)

```
abc def2 ghk
abc def ghk
abc def ghk

123 555 555
fsdjhfsda sd
566 3423 3542
```

expected result :

```
abc def ghk  123 555 555  fsdjhfsda sd
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
echo `diff -biw out.txt out2.txt | sed -n 's/^> //p'`
```

If you want to use use grep alone -- and if you can take advantage of GNU grep's formatting features -- you could use this:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format= --changed-group-format=%\> \
  --new-line-format='%l ' -biw out.txt out2.txt
```

which is probably the fastest method, and it doesn't require a large memory buffer when your files are big. (Both your original sed solution and the echo solution would keep lines in memory until the end, but this will spit them out as it goes.) The command itself is pretty verbose, though. Note also that it leaves one extra space at the end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `comm` + `tr` is similar:

```
comm --nocheck-order -13 out.txt out2.txt | tr '\n' ' '
```

Also you can put all `sed` and `grep` into one `sed`:

```
diff  -b -i -w out.txt out2.txt | sed '/^>/!{d};:a;N;$!ba;s/\n>/ /g;s/^>//'


 $ diff  -b -i -w  out.txt out2.txt | grep '^>' | sed 's/^>//g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
123 555 555  fsdjhfsda sd  566 3423 3542
 $ diff  -b -i -w out.txt out2.txt | sed '/^>/!{d};:a;N;$!ba;s/\n>/  /g;s/^>//'
123 555 555   fsdjhfsda sd   566 3423 3542
 $ comm --nocheck-order -13 out.txt out2.txt | tr '\n' '  '
123 555 555 fsdjhfsda sd 566 3423 3542
```

Comment: Nope, both of them codes do something totally different. it's output too much results that shouldn't appear. sorry.

Comment: Can you show an example of your data? It's pretty hard to guess about output. I've tried it on files `echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" > out.txt` and `echo -e "1\n2\n5\n4\n3" > out2.txt` and output was the same.

Comment: So, what's wrong? The only difference I've mentioned between expected output and output from my variants is spaces quantity in place where newline symbol was. Does it matter?

Comment: I have edited the code and give another scenario your result is `abc def[2] ghk 123 555 555 fsdjhfsda sd [566 3423 3542]` what in square brackets  `[` and `]` shouldn't appear (first code).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
diff  -b -i -w out.txt out2.txt | sed '/^>/H;$!d;g;s/\n>/ /g;s/^ *//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user@computer:~$ cat out.txt
abc def ghk
abc def2 ghk
abc def ghk

123 333 555
566 3423 23
566 3423 3542

user@computer:~$ cat out2.txt
abc def2 ghk
abc def ghk
abc def ghk

123 555 555
fsdjhfsda sd
566 3423 3542

user@computer:~$ diff out.txt out2.txt | grep '^>' | cut -d" " -f2-
abc def ghk
123 555 555
fsdjhfsda sd
```

Use `grep '^<'` to list identical lines.
For output on single line, pipe further to xargs

```
... | xargs echo
```